# opening mdb file by multiple users

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

i am new to access and am working on 2003 version

I am preparing user form in access which wish to be opened by so many users at a time.

so will this be possible?

Answer (score 2):

Ya it is possible.But the thing is you have to split the database.
Just refer the below link you wil get your answer.

```
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304932
```